# Switching between intel sandy bridge GPU and discrete video card on the fly

Tags: power-management, gpu, sandy-bridge

Is it possible to disable the discrete GPU(s) without physically fiddling with the hardware, and run the system exclusively on intel sandy bridge GPU - in order to save power? Can one do the switch without rebooting? Which desktop motherboards support this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. That functionality is provided by Lucidlogix's Virtu and it's for motherboards with H61/H67 and Z68 chipsets but I think it also requires support in the BIOS so check any specific MB your looking at.

[Virtu™ GPU Virtualization Software](http://www.lucidlogix.com/product-virtu-gpu.html)